# Download a html report, with an image inside, from a shiny app hosted in shinyapps.io

Tags: html, r, image, shiny, markdown

I want to download a html report with an image (.jpg) printed on it. It works just fine locally with the following code:

````
---
title: "Informe de ensayo"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
img(src='http://aios.pe/storage/app/media/COMACSA/header.png', align = "center")
```
````

But when I uploaded the app into shinyapps.io, I couldn't download the report anymore.

The downloaded file looks like this:

[image]

And the LOG shows this:

```
     Warning in grep("\n", x) :
     Warning in grep("^(---|\\.\\.\\.)\\s*$", lines) :
     processing file: reporte.Rmd
       string de entrada 43 es inválida en este locale
       string de entrada 43 es inválida en este locale
       string de entrada 43 es inválida en este locale

       string de entrada 43 es inválida en este locale

     Warning in grepl(chunk.end, lines) :

      |                                                                       
      |                                                                 |   0%
      |                                                                       
      |...........                                                      |  17%
     Warning in grepl(chunk.begin, lines) :

       ordinary text without R code
     List of 1

      |                                                                       
      |......................                                           |  33%
      $ echo: logi FALSE

     label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 


      |                                                                       
      |...........................................                      |  67%

      |                                                                       
      |................................                                 |  50%
     label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options) 
       ordinary text without R code
      $ echo   : logi FALSE
     List of 2
      $ results: chr "asis" 
      |                                                                       
      |......................................................           |  83%
        inline R code fragments


     Quitting from lines 39-46 (reporte.Rmd) 

     Warning: Error in nchar: invalid multibyte string, element 1
       [No stack trace available]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "stops working" mean exactly? Do you get an error of some sort?

Comment: Hi. You are right, I will add the error and a image with the (corrupted?) file